# Face Recognition with kinect

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,
I am trying to make a face Recognition with kinect ...
i have fuerte ROS
working on ubuntu 12.04 ?? f

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156811/face-recognition-with-kinect/) by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

1. In order to do that, first check the "openni" tutorial.
   This tutorial demonstrates how to open a Kinect in ROS, introduces ROS tools for visualization and configuration, etc:
   http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/QuickStart
2. Then, also check how to use a bridge between the kinect image topic and Opencv.
   This tutorial describes how to interface ROS and OpenCV by converting ROS images into OpenCV images, and vice versa, using cv_bridge. Included is a sample node that can be used as a template for your own node:
   http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython
3. Read the OpenCV documentation on how to recognize faces:
   http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html
   http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html
4. Try some example that you can found on the web, like this (I haven't tried it):
   https://code.google.com/p/ros-by-example/source/browse/trunk/rbx_vol_1/rbx1_vision/nodes/face_detector.py?r=116

I hope this links can help you, good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Hdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5773/carlos-hdz/) with karma: 103 on 2014-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to do true face ***recognition*** rather than simple face ***detection***, and you want to use ROS, check out the most excellent [cob_people_detection](http://wiki.ros.org/cob_people_detection) packages.  These packages take full advantage of the depth information from the Kinect to first look for "head-like" blobs which are likely to contain faces.  You can then train the system to recognize different faces by giving each face a name and taking a number of snapshots from different angles.

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2014-04-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on 2014-04-28**:
when I try to execute cob_people_detection
and try to know requirements for the package"""  rosdep cob_people_perception-fuerte_dev""
the following requirements  appear ::
"""
rosdep check ...
check if the dependencies of package(s) have been met.

rosdep install ...
generate a bash script and then execute it.

rosdep db
generate the dependency database and print it to the console.

rosdep init
initialize rosdep sources in /etc/ros/rosdep.  May require sudo.

rosdep keys ...
list the rosdep keys that the packages depend on.

rosdep resolve 
resolve  to system dependencies

rosdep update
update the local rosdep database based on the rosdep sources.

rosdep what-needs ...
print a list of packages that declare a rosdep on (at least
one of)

rosdep where-defined ...
print a list of yaml files that declare a rosdep on (at least
one of)    """???